# Index out of range?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector

Below are two 2D objects, Array and Vector. As you can see the information described in both is identically. My game works flawlessly using the Array object, but with Vector is throws the following error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=RangeError: Error #1125: The index 10 is out of range 10. 

var _platformMap:Array = [
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [00, 00, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 00, 00, 00, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 00, 00, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00]
     ];

var _platformMap:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = Vector.<Vector.<int>>(
        [
            Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([00,00,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,01,01,01,10,10,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([10,10,10,00,10,10,10,10,01,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([10,10,10,00,10,10,01,01,01,00]), 
            Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,01,01,01,01,01,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([00,00,00,00,00,10,10,10,10,10]), 
            Vector.<int>([00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00])
        ]
    );
```

I read about that Vector objects have runtime range checking (or fixed-length checking) besides Arrays. Could this be the problem?

```
public class TileCollisionController
{
    private var _softPlatformOpen:Boolean = true;
    private var _elevatorOpen:Boolean = true;

    public function TileCollisionController()
    {}

    public function platformCollision(gameObject:TileModel, platformMap:Vector.<Vector.<int>>, maxTileSize:uint, platform:uint):void
    {
        var overlapX:Number;
        var overlapY:Number;
        //check top-left corner
        if (platformMap[gameObject.top][gameObject.left] == platform)
        {
            overlapX = gameObject.xPos % maxTileSize;
            overlapY = gameObject.yPos % maxTileSize;
            if (overlapY >= overlapX)
            {
                if (gameObject.vy < 0 && platformMap[gameObject.bottom][gameObject.left] != platform)
                {
                    //Collision on top side of the object
                    gameObject.setY = gameObject.mapRow * maxTileSize;
                    gameObject.vy = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Collision on left side of the object
                gameObject.setX = gameObject.mapColumn * maxTileSize;
                gameObject.vx = 0;
            }
        }
        //check top-right corner
        if (platformMap[gameObject.top][gameObject.right] == platform)
        {
            overlapX = maxTileSize - ((gameObject.xPos + gameObject.width) % maxTileSize);
            overlapY = gameObject.yPos % maxTileSize;
            if (overlapY >= overlapX)
            {
                if (gameObject.vy < 0 && platformMap[gameObject.bottom][gameObject.right] != platform)
                {
                    gameObject.setY = (gameObject.mapRow * maxTileSize);
                    gameObject.vy = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Collision on right
                gameObject.setX = (gameObject.mapColumn * maxTileSize) + ((maxTileSize - gameObject.width) - 1);
                gameObject.vx = 0;
            }
        }
        //check bottom-left corner
        if (platformMap[gameObject.bottom][gameObject.left] == platform)
        {
            overlapX = gameObject.xPos % maxTileSize;
            overlapY = maxTileSize - ((gameObject.yPos + gameObject.height) % maxTileSize);
            if (overlapY >= overlapX)
            {
                if (gameObject.vy > 0 && platformMap[gameObject.top][gameObject.left] != platform)
                {
                    //trace("Collision on bottom");
                    //Collision on bottom
                    gameObject.setY = (gameObject.mapRow * maxTileSize) + (maxTileSize - gameObject.height);
                    gameObject.vy = 0;
                    gameObject.jumping = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //trace("Collision on bottom left");
                //Collision on left
                gameObject.setX = gameObject.mapColumn * maxTileSize;
                gameObject.vx = 0;
            }
        }
        //check bottom-right corner
        if (platformMap[gameObject.bottom][gameObject.right] == platform)
        {
            overlapX = maxTileSize - ((gameObject.xPos + gameObject.width) % maxTileSize);
            overlapY = maxTileSize - ((gameObject.yPos + gameObject.height) % maxTileSize);
            if (overlapY >= overlapX)
            {
                if (gameObject.vy > 0 && platformMap[gameObject.top][gameObject.right] != platform)
                {
                    //trace("Collision on bottom right");
                    //Collision on bottom
                    gameObject.setY = (gameObject.mapRow * maxTileSize) + (maxTileSize - gameObject.height);
                    gameObject.vy = 0;
                    gameObject.jumping = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //trace("Collision on right");
                //Collision on right
                gameObject.setX = (gameObject.mapColumn * maxTileSize) + ((maxTileSize - gameObject.width) - 1);
                gameObject.vx = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}
[See example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/picbi.jpg/)

```
    public function platformCollision(gameObject:TileModel, platformMap:Vector.<Vector.<int>>, maxTileSize:uint, platform:uint):void
    {
        var overlapX:Number;
        var overlapY:Number;
        if(gameObject.bottom < platformMap.length && gameObject.right < platformMap[0].length)
        {
        //check top-left corner
        //...
```

[Example after updates](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/248/pic2cu.jpg/)

Comment: if you allow me so i will try to help you.this code like c code.how many index array is this i know but want to know.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/any-which-array-but-loose here is a presentation to help you understand arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, but neither of those have an object at index 10? Maybe you should be looking at index 9 as it starts at 0?

Could you show how you are accessing the array/vector? I think that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: The error appears on this line: if (platformMap[gameObject.bottom][gameObject.right] == platform)

Comment: I think it is because you are looking for something at index 10. so when 'gameObject.bottom = 10' it will throw that error. do some sort of check to make sure it doesn't look at an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have changed the collision code and added a check before the collision testing starts. It works ok, but now, gameObject can freely move between the environmental bricks from in the last row, which is not ok. You can see the updates in the post.

Comment: If that is all you have changed then you need to make sure it does do a check on index 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var platformMap:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>(2);(
                [
                    Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([00,00,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,01,01,01,10,10,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([10,10,10,00,10,10,10,10,01,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([10,10,10,00,10,10,01,01,01,00]), 
                    Vector.<int>([10,10,10,10,01,01,01,01,01,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([00,00,00,00,00,10,10,10,10,10]), 
                    Vector.<int>([00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00])
                ]);
```

Comment: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 2 to __AS3__.vec.Vector.<__AS3__.vec::Vector.<int>>.

Answer (score 0):

the vectors length is 10, so you can access from 0 to 9.
the vectors contain vectors, what also have a len.
try

```
trace("maxnumallowed", platformMap.length-1)
```

and note, that you can only access platformMap[n], if n is between 0 and platformMap.length-1

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is why is working ok with arrays? I am not doing any bounds-check. The code is similar in both cases. Why are vectors so stubborn?

Comment: @LuciM: The just are. It's like how `Vector`s have a data type and `Array`s don't, they're just a more strict form of `Array`s. This can sometimes effect optimization, but in my view the most useful point of them is for shared or automated code, to prevent weird stuff happening that `Array`s would allow. Which you should use really depends on your code, and how specific or general it is.